# Codeigniter - selecting children and parents from db

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pull from my database records corresponding to `parent_id`, like this:

```
function getChildren($id, $parent_id) {
    $q = $this->db->select('id, name, slug, plat');
    $q = $this->db->from('games');
    $q = $this->db->where('parent_id',$id);
    $q = $this->db->or_where('id',$parent_id);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

It - if it's a children game - get `parent_id` and search for a game with such `id` and for other games that has `parent_id` same as this one. If it's the parent game, it only looks for games with `parent_id` same as it's `id`.

The problem is... it's not always working. I have four games in db:

```
id  |  parent_id  |  title
15  |  0          |  Abe
19  |  15         |  Abe
20  |  0          |  RE2
21  |  20         |  RE2 DS
```

First two works, last two - only children (`id = 21`) shows parent.

Comment: can you please more clearify your question and put your desired result

Answer (score 1):

You likely could not do that with a **relation database**. RDBMS are not intended to manage any form of trees.

You *can* in some simple case, like one-level hierarchy, but as soon as it becomes more complex, it's getting messier and messier.

Keeping your structure, you have to make **ONE JOIN per LEVEL**, and that means knowing the depth in advance.

A solution to store trees in database is called Nested Tree, it basically stores interval for in each rows, but it is a bit complex to implement by yourself.

Take a look at [Wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). There are however library which allows you to programmatically abstract such operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
select 
    * 
from games as g
where parent_id = 0
union all
select
    l.*
from games r 
left join (select * from games) as l on r.id = t.id
where
r.parent_id != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting my problem, I tried another solution. Funny, I sit with this for more than an hour and after wasting your time, I came with the solution ;)

Anyway, here it is:

```
function getChildren($id, $parent_id) {
    $q = $this->db->select('id, name, slug, plat');
    $q = $this->db->from('games');
    $q = $this->db->where('parent_id',$id);
    $q = $this->db->or_where('id',$parent_id);
    $q = $this->db->or_where('parent_id',$parent_id);
    $q = $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return $q->result_array();
}
```